# How to select only the top 1000 rows when importing from SQL to power bi?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I am trying to import data from a SQL server into power BI. There is a section on the advanced options called SQL statement.

I know that the SQL statement for what I require is:

```
Select TOP 1000 * from [Table]
```

How do I write this in the Power Bi at the time of data source / import. So that it runs this statement for each of the tables I plan to import?

Comment: You mean `TOP 1000 *`

Comment: @Sami Yes, thank you!

Comment: I've never used it, but a quick look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-data-sources and it says 'ou can either load the data by selecting the Load button at the bottom of the Navigator pane, or edit the query before loading data' Bear in mind that without ORDER BY... you would be selecting ANY 1000 records - even if it might seem that they are in key order, they would not be guaranteed to be.

Comment: @Cato I'm trying to edit the query, but I don't know how to add in the table name as a variable to run through all the tables.

Comment: You can get help from here from my article about keeping and deleting rows in Power BI https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/variable-in-dax-keep-rows-and-remove-rows-in-power-bi/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this at the time of importing SQL Server data.

[image]

After loading data you can keep and remove rows using keep rows as shown below

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can get help from an article written by me for keeping and removing rows in Power BI https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/variable-in-dax-keep-rows-and-remove-rows-in-power-bi/

Comment: This is only for one table. I need it for multiple tables

Comment: @Fabio It is not available one click option to keep and delete few rows to several tables. But you can definitely do it when you write query such as views and importing it as data source.

Comment: @Fabio Even this facility is not available in SQL Server back up or restore to keep only few selected records.

Comment: How about copying the database then making a T-SQL program loop to delete all but 5 records in all tables, using dynamic SQL - is one route I can think of

Comment: Yes you can go for it and import that db or table.

Answer (score 1):

If all the tables you want are on the same database, then you can navigate to that database as the first step in your query.

[image: Database]

From there, filter down to select just the tables you want.

[image: Filter Rows]

(You can see the preview of the cell selected in the bottom pane.)

Now that you've got the tables you want, you can apply a TopN function to the entire column (I chose top 3).

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Data", each Table.FirstN(_,3), type table}})
```

A quick way to add this step is to do a transformation on a text column and then just replace the column and the function applied. For example, if you format the `Schema` column to UPPERCASE using the GUI, it will add the step

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Schema", Text.Upper, type text}})
```

from which you can swap out the column, function, and type for what you actually want (see previous).

[image: Top 3]

At this point, your tables are all trimmed to the top N rows and you can load each one to its own query by right-clicking on the table cell and choosing "Add as New Query". Alternatively, you can right-click on the `Database` query in the left pane (see the first image) and choose "Reference". This creates a new query from which you can simply click on the Table you want and it will return just that one.

*Note: The former method will automatically name the new query after the table you expanded but the latter would work better if you wanted to change your* `N` *value since it doesn't recreate the whole query.*

Either way, if you right-click on the last applied step in each of these new tables, you can choose "View Native Query" and you can see that the statement passed back to the server is a simple `select top 3`.

```
select top 3
    [$Table].[DealSpecificKey] as [DealSpecificKey],
    [$Table].[DateInvestment] as [DateInvestment],
    [$Table].[DateInvestmentKey] as [DateInvestmentKey],
    [$Table].[DateRedemption] as [DateRedemption],
    [$Table].[DateRedemptionKey] as [DateRedemptionKey]
from [dbo].[AuxDaysInvested] as [$Table]
```